# solving matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to solve the following matrix equation. Could anyone give me a hand? Thanks.

Given an $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf A$ (diagonally dominant), I need to solve an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $\mathbf  X$ such that

$\mathbf A\mathbf X+\mathbf X\mathbf A^\top =\mathbf  I$,

where $\mathbf I$ is an $n \times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: I don't get the question. Let A=0, then surely no such X exists.
Also, please remove those irrelevant tags.

Comment: We assume that $A$ is a nonzero matrix.

Comment: Is $A$ *strictly* diagonally dominant? If so, $A$ is of course non-zero.

Comment: Yeah, it is strictly diagonally dominant.

Comment: By Gershgorin circle theorem, diagonally dominated matrices are non-singular.  Therefore A inverse(which is square) exists

Answer (score 2):

If you are just going to use it for purposes of computation etc. then it seems to me that the simplest way is to consider this as A'X'=B', where A' is $n^2 \times n^2$, X' is $n^2 \times 1$, B' is $n^2 \times 1$. X' and B' are basically 'flattened' versions of X and I, respectively. If general element of X is $x_{ij}$, then $x_{ij}$ is also $(i \times (n-1) + j)$th element of X'. Similarly for getting B' from I. $(i \times (n-1) + j), (k \times (n-1) + l)$th element of A' is number of times $x_ij$ contributes to (k,l)th element in the expansion of the LHS here. So eg. $a'_{11}$ is $2 \times a_{11}$.

Comment: This is effectively the "Kronecker product" approach I was alluding to in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a special case of a [Sylvester equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation). The wiki page I linked to describes both the eigenvalue and Kronecker product approaches to solving the equation, but in practice, one uses algorithms like the one by [Bartels and Stewart](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/361573.361582).